# First occurence of a character in string

Tags: c++, string

I am aware of the method `strchr` which find first occurrence of any character in the character array.But how to find first occurrence of any character in string?

More specifically,I want any method to do this-->

```
     john.smith@codeforces.ru/contest.icpc/12
```

On searching for `@` it should give 10 and on searching for `/` it should give 25 and not 38.

Comment: Documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: See also [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::string::find(char c)`:

```
std::string a = "john.smith@codeforces.ru/contest.icpc/12";
cout << a.find('.') << endl; //4
cout << a.find('/') << endl; //24
```

Comment: yes its working but why is it giving me error when i change '/' to '\'. Something like "missing terminating ' character".

Comment: @chotabheem If you want to know that, then ask that question. Not some completely different one.

Comment: @juanchopanza No i want to know this only..But accidentally i changed the slashes and noticed this error that's why i asked.

Comment: You need to [escape](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is `std::string::find_first_of()`

```
std::string str("john.smith@codeforces.ru/contest.icpc/12");
str.find_first_of("@");   // returns 10
str.find_first_of("@/");  // returns 10
str.find_first_of("/");   // returns 24 .. or so
```

Comment: Why "@/" i mean why backslash

Answer (score 1):

For the string you showed to get the result you are expecting for character `'/'` in the string you should use the expressions as they are written in the program below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "john.smith@codeforces.ru/contest.icpc/12";

    std::cout << s.find( '/' ) + 1  << std::endl;
    std::cout << s.rfind( '/' ) + 1 << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
25
38
```

Take into account that the position starts from 0.

Otherwise use simply `s.find()` and/or `s.rfind()`.